# Getting IP address list between two IP addresses

Tags: java, javascript, ip, ipv4

I am writing a program that gets From IP address and To IP address from the user and displays the list of IP addresses between them. For example, if the user gives 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.5 then I will display the five IP addresses between these two. The current solution that is coming in my mind are:

1. To have a list of all IP addresses and then look for the resultant IP address list
2. Use a nested loop

What solution should I adopt between these (or suggest a better solution)? For the first solution, what is the link for IP address table/list?

What is the solution in terms of JavaScript or Java?

Comment: Why do you want this? Is it for subnet scanning?

Comment: yes I am scanning the subnets. for this purpose I have got a scripts that tells the from and to IPs and now I want to save all these IPs in separate rows

Comment: So if this were to run in a browser it could be used to scan the clients internal network?

Comment: there can be some external networks also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First split the IP addresses with `.`. From the first IP address, start increasing the fourth part up to 255 and then add 1 to the third part and set the fourth one to 1. Until you reach the to IP address.

- IP address bytes -> bits -> Int32
- From: `10.0.10.10` -> `00001010 00000000 00001010 00001010` -> `167774730`
- To: `10.1.45.1` -> `00001010 00000001 00101101 00000001` -> `167849217`
- Start count from From to To and just check the unwanted bytes which is `11111111` and `00000000`.

That's all.

Comment: No. 0 is for the "name" of the net. By the way 255 is for broadcast, so this will not be usable, too. But that was not part of the op's question. He wants addresses, not "usable" addresses.

Comment: Whether .0 is for the name of the net depends on the subnet mask. If the mask is 255.255.0.0, then the name of the net is x.y.0.0, but x.y.2.0 is just an ordinary address.

Comment: yes Amir, splitting is a solution but I was wondering to have list of ordered IP addresses and then get the IP lists by index or between query in terms of DB. Consider a sorted list of IPs in DB like 10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.2 - 10.0.0.3 etc. So between query will be easy

Comment: So you should use Int32 value of IP address. Each IP has 4 Bytes so by putting their bits we could create an Int32 witch is indexable and queryable.

Comment: Also consider the case for 10.0.10.10 and 10.1.45.1. I want to avoid nested loops and multiple if else statements. Thanks

Comment: That's correct @Barmar. Doesn't change the fact though, that he would have to filter out special cases anyway if he wants "usable" addresses, only.

Comment: Unless you know the architecture of the network you're scanning, there's no way to know which special cases should be filtered out. Anyway, that's a separate problem from enumerating the addresses.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 3):

The "dot"-writing is for humans. For computers, it is one 4-byte-number. So parse it to a number. Then you will get all addresses in the range by simply increasing a number until the bound is reached and format them back for output.

Answer (score 2):

I was experimenting in [an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhyLS/4/), and finally I came to the solution below. The following code should work for all IP addresses. You have to provide a start and end IP address in hex (since it is easy, I did not write code for it).

```
var startIp = 0x0A000001,
endIp = 0x0A000F05;

var  temp, list = [],str;
for(var i=startIp ; i <= endIp ; i++){
    temp = (i).toString(16);
    str ='';
    if(temp.length == 7){
        temp = "0"+temp;
    }

    for(var k=temp.length-1; k  >= 0 ; k-=2){
       str = parseInt(temp[k-1] + "" + temp[k], 16) +"." + str ;
    }
    document.write(temp + " " + str+ "<br>");
    list.push(str.substring(0, str.length-1));
}

?
```

Comment: Since it only works when the first three components are the same, why do you bother with the i, j, and k loops?

Comment: Initially I was trying to make it work for all values. but it is not easy I have consider many cases.

Comment: Also consider the case for 10.0.10.10 and 10.1.45.1. I want to avoid nested loops and multiple if else statements. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

If you know enough to get the addresses (from the network or from the file system or user input), you can test the address itself with subtraction and get the number of IP addresses right there.

This is simplified, but you will get it if you know about addresses: `000044-000002 = 000042`.

Comment: You will need to enumerate a bit about the target network, but that is described there in the netmask.