# Find the network distance between two IPv4 addresses (not geographic distance)

Tags: php, python, networking

Given an IPv4 address (needle) and an unsorted array of IPv4 addresses (haystack), how could I programmatically determine which single address in the given haystack is the closest (network-wise, NOT geographically) to the needle?

Since I don't have access to the netmask of every address, the solution should ignore netmasks and traceroute alike options.

All sorts of addresses are used, by which I mean: private, reserved, broadcast, lan and wan.

Any help in the form of theory, pseudo-code, python, php or perl is welcome.

The question [Getting IP address list between two IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597192/getting-ip-address-list-between-two-ip-addresses) is roughly similar, but it does quite cut it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "closest network wise"?

Comment: not sure exactly what you are mean by closest?   as for your all sorts of address, they are all just IPs  Without a netmask, the network/broadcast status of the address is unknown.  LAN/WAN are used for human understanding.   Pretty much and IP is an IP is an IP.  The being said do you mean if giving needle of 10.10.0.1, and haystack of '10.20.0.1, 10.30.0.1, 10.10.0.0, 10.10.0.3'  the program would spit back 10.10.0.0 ? as it is the closest numerically?

Comment: also thing like Net::Cidr in perl (and python) but without masks it gets tough..

Comment: @PeterGibson by closest I meant, 192.168.1.101 is closer to 192.168.56.1 than to 172.30.130.66 . And 192.168.1.254 is closer to 192.168.1.240 than to 192.168.2.1

Comment: @Doon The problem ignores whether the IP is broadcast, multicast, private, etc.. It deal with all IPs from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 the exact same way. If you're jumping IP by IP, how many hops would take to reach your destination - regardless of route.

Comment: @msantos but what rules are you applying,  since if ignoring subnet masks,  192.168.2.1 is 2 IPS from 192.168.1.254 and 14 IPS away from 1.240 (assuming > /23 mask). In your example you are still applying subnets.  If you are just looking for "distance"  convert both ips to integers and look at the absolute value of the difference between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure what you're asking, but based on your comment

> @PeterGibson by closest I meant, 192.168.1.101 is closer to
>   192.168.56.1 than to 172.30.130.66 . And 192.168.1.254 is closer to 192.168.1.240 than to 192.168.2.1

You could try the following python code for a distance function:

```
import socket
def dist(a, b):
    def to_num(addr):
        # parse the address string into integer quads
        quads = map(ord, socket.inet_aton(addr))
        # spread the quads out 
        return reduce(lambda x,y: x * 0x10000 + y, quads)
    return abs(to_num(a) - to_num(b))
```

The numbers returned are fairly arbitrary, but should suffice for basic needs. I'm still not sure what it should do with broadcast addresses etc though.

Some examples:

```
>>> dist('192.168.1.254', '192.168.1.240')
14L
>>> dist('192.168.1.254', '192.168.2.1')
65283L
>>> dist('192.168.1.101', '192.168.56.1')
3604380L
>>> dist('192.168.1.101', '172.30.130.66')
5630092231245859L
```

Comment: A similar approach in PHP would be <pre>    $min = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $rtn = false;
    $l1 = ip2long($src_ip);
    foreach($list as $ip)
    {
        $l2 = ip2long($ip);
        $d = ($l1 > $l2) ? $l1 - $l2 : $l2 - $l1;
        if ($min > $d) {
            $rtn = $ip;
            $min = $d;
        }
    }

    echo "$rtn\n";

Comment: @msantos, your solution doesn't seem to meet your requirement of `192.168.1.254` being closer to `192.168.1.240` than to `192.168.2.1` whilst mine does.

Comment: @PeterGibson why 'x * 0x10000' instead of 'x * 0x100' ?

Comment: @auxten to emphasise the difference between OPs concept of subnets (ie so that 192.168.1.254 is closer to 192.168.1.240 than to 192.168.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by dividing array into groups, considering reserved ip-addresses (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses). Then i'd separate them by regions. Maybe some tree structure would suffice: root nodes are top level regions and then, closing to leafs it goes for smaller regions.

Comment: The problem ignores whether the IP is broadcast, multicast, private, etc.. It deal with all IPs from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 the exact same way. The goal is *not* to find the shortest route. But instead is to find how many IP away two addresses are.

Comment: Oh, something like this `DISTANCE('192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.5') == 4` ?

Comment: Then just convert your addresses to hexadecimal, and use some binary search tree

Comment: DISTANCE('192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.5') == 4 **and** DISTANCE('192.168.1.1', '192.168.0.252') == 4, *but* since 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.252 are **likely** to be in the same network, they are the closest nodes.

Comment: that is a rather big assumption that they are likely to be in the same network.  perhaps in the world of soho based routers they are. but there are lots of networks that use masks besides /24

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest of the approaches, but since very high performance is not required, it does the job.

```
<?php

$ip = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : '192.168.1.254';
printf("Input => %s => %u\n", $ip, ip2long($ip));

var_dump(
    net_distance(
        $ip,
        array(
            '87.86.85.84',
            '173.194.41.170',
            '192.168.1.150',
            '192.168.1.245',
            '192.168.2.2',
            '192.168.56.50',
        )
    )
);

// The problem assumes that:
// a) any local (127) and lan (10,172,192) IPs are closer to each other than to any wan IP.
// b) any wan IP is closer to local and lan IPs than to other wan IP.
function net_distance($src_ip, $list)
{
  if (in_array($src_ip, $list)) {
    return $src_ip; // exact match
  }

  list($a0, $b0, $c0, $d0) = explode('.', $src_ip, 4);

  $triples = array();
  $doubles = array();
  $singles = array();

  foreach($list as $ip) {
    list($a1, $b1, $c1, $d1) = explode('.', $ip, 4);

    if ($a0 == $a1 && $b0 == $b1 && $c0 == $c1) { // match A.B.C.x
      $triples[] = $ip;
    }
    elseif ($a0 == $a1 && $b0 == $b1) { // match A.B.x.y
      $doubles[] = $ip;
    }
    elseif ($a0 == $a1 || (in_array($a0, array(127, 10, 172, 192)) && in_array($a1, array(127, 10, 172, 192)))) {
      $singles[] = $ip; // match A.x.y.z or both As are *likely* to be lan addresses
    }
  }

  if (count($triples) > 0) {
    $list = $triples;
  }
  elseif (count($doubles) > 0) {
    $list = $doubles;
  }
  elseif (count($singles) > 0) {
    $list = $singles;
  }

  $min = PHP_INT_MAX;
  $rtn = false;
  $l1 = ip2long($src_ip);
  foreach($list as $ip)
  {
    $l2 = ip2long($ip);
    $d = ($l1 > $l2) ? $l1 - $l2 : $l2 - $l1;
    // echo "\t" . str_pad($ip, 15, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT) . " => $l2 => $d\n";
    if ($min > $d) {
      $rtn = $ip;
      $min = $d;
    }
  }

  return $rtn;
}
```